# Pytorch: can we use nn.Module layers directly in forward() function?

Tags: python, constructor, pytorch, conv-neural-network, forward

Generally,
In the constructor, we declare all the layers we want to use.
In the forward function, we define how the model is going to be run, from input to output.

My question is what if calling those predefined/built-in **nn.Modules** directly in `forward()` function? Is this [**Keras function API**](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) style legal for **Pytorch**? If not, why?

Update: **TestModel** constructed in this way did run successfully, without an alarm. But the training loss will descend slowly compared with the conventional way.

```py
import torch.nn as nn
from cnn import CNN

class TestModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_embeddings = 2020
        self.embedding_dim = 51

    def forward(self, input):
        x = nn.Embedding(self.num_embeddings, self.embedding_dim)(input)
        # CNN is a customized class and nn.Module subclassed
        # we will ignore the arguments for its instantiation 
        x = CNN(...)(x)
        x = nn.ReLu()(x)
        x = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)(x)
        return output = x
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to put these modules into forward method?

Comment: @AndreasK. Not particularly, but this style seems more neat. Is there another `pytorch way` to enable the variables/parameters trainable in `forward()`, other than initialize first in `constructor`?

Answer (score 10):

You need to think of the *scope* of the trainable parameters.

If you define, say, a conv layer in the `forward` function of your model, then the scope of this  "layer" and its trainable parameters is *local* to the function and will be discarded after every call to the `forward` method. You cannot update and train weights that are constantly being discarded after every `forward` pass.
However, when the conv layer is a member of your `model` its scope extends beyond the `forward` method and the trainable parameters persists as long as the `model` object exists. This way you can update and train the model and its weights.

Comment: Will those weights of `nn.Module` in forward() initialize every time calling `forward()`? Would you explain more or advise some reference links on how pytorch manage the scope of parameters?

Comment: @Kuo you can start with [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-in-python-legb-rule/) tutorial about python's scope rules.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do kinda can be done, but shouldn't as it's totally unnecessary in most cases. And it's not more readable IMO and definitely against PyTorch's way.

In your `forward` layers are reinitialized every time and they are not registered in your network.

To do it correctly you can use `Module`'s `add_module()` function with guard against reassignment (method `dynamic` below):

```
import torch

class Example(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_embeddings = 2020        
        self.embedding_dim = 51 

    def dynamic(self, name: str, module_class, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self, name):
            self.add_module(name, module_class(*args, **kwargs))
        return getattr(self, name)

    def forward(self, x):
        embedded = self.dynamic("embedding",
                     torch.nn.Embedding,
                     self.num_embeddings,
                     self.embedding_dim)(x)
        return embedded
```

You could structure it differently but that's the idea standing behind it.

Real use case could be when the layer's creation is somehow dependent on the data passed to `forward`, but this may indicate some flaws in program design.

Comment: I like this example how to manipulate module dynamically, though tricky but innovative for me. Combining your Pytorch example and Shai's basic python explanation, I learned a lot.